# How to handle duplicate question from another server?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions, cross-posting

I found basically identical questions - I saw one on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768351/itunes-connect-remove-apps) and immediately saw *something rotten in the state of Denmark* because *this* question has definitely been asked before. So I went and googled it for the OP and found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153931/is-it-a-way-to-remove-app-from-itunes-connect) question, which is basically the same. The problems are:

1. I can't flag that it is duplicate of question on another server.
2. I can't flag that this question belongs to **Ask Different** because it is not in the list of off-topic choices.
3. Even if I did manage to do **2.** I would introduce duplicate question on **Ask Different**.

What I did was simply comment that there are two similar questions out there, but surely that doesn't really fix this issue. What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: @user4098326 Duplicate question about duplicates. Too bad I couldn't come up with the word **cross-site**. Thanks!

Comment: @user4098326 One question remains unanswered though - **2.**. There is not an option to migrate it to Ask Different. How to flag that?

Comment: Flag as "Other" and explain why it needs to be moved. If the moderator will agree, he/she can migrate to any site in Stack Exchange. (assuming the question is not more than 60 days old)